# Rotational invariance of Bell state

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

In [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivmThsbkhTU) on quantum mechanics, Umesh Vazirani shows with a simple calculation that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|11\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|uu\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u^\perp u^\perp \rangle$$

for any state $u$.  Taking away the physics notation, I translate this as

$$e_1 \otimes e_1 +  e_2 \otimes e_2 = u\otimes u + u^\perp \otimes u^\perp$$

in the the vector space $V \otimes V$, $V = \mathbb{C}^2$, where $e_1,e_2$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $u, u^\perp$ is any another basis attained by applying a (real) rotation to $e_1, e_2$.  Is there a coordinate-free or more conceptual proof than the one Vazirani gives?  What's the geometric meaning of this vector? Can we generalize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark 1:** In quantum mechanics, the most general transformation mapping pure states of a two-level quantum system (aka *qubit*) to other pure states is represented as a *unitary* matrix in $SU(2)$. However, as Vazirani points out in the video and you note in your question, his proof only applies to *real rotations*, i.e. matrices in $SO(2) \subset SU(2)$.

---

**Proof:** Let $\beta_{00} = |00\rangle + |11\rangle$ where we ignore normalization since vector norm is preserved by unitary transformations. A key property of $\beta_{00}$ which we need is that for any $A \in GL(2, \mathbb{C})$

$$
(A \otimes I) \beta_{00} = (I \otimes A^T) \beta_{00}\tag1.
$$

This can be shown easily by writing it out in the matrix notation or by following indices in the tensor notation. However, since you requested a coordinate-free or more conceptual proof, we will instead use tensor networks employing some basic properties shown in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006). Note that the tensor network representation of $\beta_{00}$ is a simple bend (so called "cup") and $(1)$ is merely a restatement of equation $(46)$ in the paper.

Now, let $U \in SO(2)$ be the real rotation that maps $|0\rangle$ to $|u\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ to $|u^\perp\rangle$. Applying it to both qubits and using $(1)$ we obtain

$$
(U \otimes U) \beta_{00} = (I \otimes U^TU) \beta_{00}
$$

but $U$ is orthogonal so

$$
(U \otimes U) \beta_{00} = \beta_{00}.
$$

On the other hand,

$$
(U \otimes U) \beta_{00} = |uu\rangle + |u^\perp u^\perp\rangle.
$$

Comparing the last two equations, we obtain the desired rotational invariance.

---

**Remark 2:** For a generic unitary $U$ the proof above fails, because $U^TU$ is not necessarily identity. For a concrete counterexample consider $U=S$ where

$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where we obtain

$$
(S \otimes S)\beta_{00} = |00\rangle - |11\rangle \ne \beta_{00}.
$$

---

**Remark 3:** We can generalize the above result if we replace $\beta_{00}$ with a different Bell state. In his video Vazirani mentions that $\beta_{11} = |01\rangle - |10\rangle$ is invariant under *general* unitary transformations. Let us see how this happens.

First, note that $\beta_{11} = (Z \otimes X)\beta_{00}$ where

$$
Z = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \,\,\,\,
X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

From equation $(45)$ in the paper linked above, we see that $\beta_{11}$ is the [Levi-Civita tensor in two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Two_dimensions). An important property of this tensor, expressed in $(12)$ in the paper, is

$$
(U \otimes U)\beta_{11} = (\det U) \beta_{11}.
$$

Thus, for $U \in SU(2)$ we have

$$
(U \otimes U)\beta_{11} = \beta_{11}
$$

so $\beta_{11}$ is invariant under arbitrary unitary transformations in $SU(2)$ applied to both qubits.

Comment: Really helpful, thank you!